# Ubuntu 18.04 and libwayland-egl.so.1 issue

Tags: software-installation

After update of my Kubuntu 18.04 (few days ago) some applications say that libwayland-egl.so.1 is missing.
For example - Firefox: libwayland-egl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

The same info I receive in case of opera, chromium and many other programs.
I've tried to reach solution in google but with no success.
I have got libwayland-egl1-mesa installed in newest version.

Comment: Update: the same issue appeared few minutes ago on my desktop.

Comment: Do the programs you mentioned run properly?

Comment: No, programs do not start at all, not only web browser but many others (f.e. Synaptic). As I mentioned the same issue appeared on my both computers, both with radeon graph.

Answer (score 2):

Running the following command solved the problem for me.

```
apt install libwayland-egl1
```

Source: [Padoka: latest mesa breaks wayland – workaround](https://wordpress.padoka.org/2018/06/09/latest-mesa-breaks-wayland-workaround/)

Comment: Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `libegl1-mesa-dev`

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install qtwayland5
```

solved my problem